Not receiving validation errors instead received 200 status
I am using AOP @Around annotation and ControllerAdvice.
I have UserDto class with validation size max=1
Whenever I am using @Around Aop I am not receiving validation errors
though the handleMethodArgumentNotValid  method had executed.
If i use @Before, AfterReturning i am getting validation errors
AOP
@Around("execution(* com.comp..*(..))")
public void aroundAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  log.info("around aspect started");
  joinPoint.proceed();
  log.info("around aspect ended");
}

UserDto
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserDto {
  @Size(max = 1)
  public String username;
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
  MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request
)
{
  log.info("Method exception handler");

  Map<String, String> validationErrors = new HashMap<>();
  List<ObjectError> validationErrorList = ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors();
  validationErrorList.forEach((error) -> {
    String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
    String validationMsg = error.getDefaultMessage();
    validationErrors.put(fieldName, validationMsg);
  });
  log.info("validation errors {}", validationErrors);

  ErrorResponseDto errorResponseDto = new ErrorResponseDto(
    request.getDescription(false),
    validationErrors,
    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
    LocalDateTime.now().toString()
  );
  log.info("Error response {}", errorResponseDto);

  return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponseDto, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

I am expecting though I use @Around validation should happen

I believe the issue with @Around advice arises when exceptions are not properly handled or when the result from joinPoint.proceed() is not returned. This can lead to the validation logic not being correctly propagated.
Updated code(tried to return the result),
@Around("execution(* com.comp..*(..))")
public Object aroundAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  log.info("around aspect started");
  Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
  log.info("around aspect ended");
  return result; // RETURN THE RESULT
}


Exactly. A void return type for an @Around advice only makes sense if all intercepted target methods also return void. Otherwise, the advice will yield default values like null, 0  or false. Jayesh, please be polite and either mark this answer as accepted or comment on it, if there is any problem with it.
